# Curl having issue with brace/bracket

Tags: shell, curl, escaping, quotes, curly-braces

I am trying to execute the following line in .sh file:

```
test2='{"admins":{"names":["superuser"],"roles":["admins", "test"]}}'
curl $url -X PUT -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: application/json' -d $test2
```

it would give me an error like

```
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 7
```

However, when I run the command without a shell variable like this

```
curl $url -X PUT -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: application/json' -d '{"admins":{"names":["superuser"],"roles":["admins", "test"]}}'
```

it works fine.

What is going on here.  Very puzzled.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried escaping the double quotes?

Comment: You have to quote the expansion: `-d "$test2"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (Escaping double quotes and using `"$test2"` instead)

```
test2="{\"admins\":{\"names\":[\"superuser\"],\"roles\":[\"admins\", \"test\"]}}"
curl $url -X PUT -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: application/json' -d "$test2"
```

Comment: This fixes it, but not because of escaping the double quotes; the first line is equivalent to the question's first line. The important difference is `"$test2"` instead of `$test2` to suppress globbing.

Comment: @BenjaminW. and @funkyhelly . `"$test2"` . works for me ;) . thank you so much. was playing with it this whole afternoon...